# Why doesn't but-2-yne show acidic character?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, resonance, hydrocarbons

I found this in several sources and also found this while solving a few questions that but-2-yne does not show acidic character (or atleast not a significant  amount of acidity) compared to terminal alkynes

This could easily be attributed to the fact that but-2-yne doesnt have a hydrogen attached to a sp hybridised carbon.

However I felt that if the methyl group attached to the sp hybridised carbon was to donate a proton,  the resulting anion would be resonance stabilized,  because there has to exist a pi bond in the plane of the lone pair on the terminal carbon.

I couldn't see why this resonance shouldn't be possible,  as pi electrons are spread out over 3 atoms(though in different planes) , instead of all of them being concentrated between 2 atoms in a triple bond.

But I couldn't find an explanation anywhere for this.  Please help

Comment: Your analysis is quite correct. The only hitch is that that CH group is *so* weakly acidic that even a bit of resonance stabilisation can't make it significantly acidic. Look up the pKa of toluene, for example: that has *one whole aromatic ring* to delocalise the negative charge around, and its pKa is still larger than 40.

Comment: But most of the sources said that terminal alkynes were more acidic than but-2-yne. But by resonance it should atleast be more acidic than the regular terminal alkynes right? (Marginally but still comparable)

Comment: However removing the proton is difficult in the first place. You are having to remove it from a sp3 carbon which doesn't stabilise the the negative charge very well in the first place

Comment: @SafdarFaisal But doesn't resonance compensate that?

Comment: Well, resonance is not this one factor which automatically trumps everything else. Resonance can be *very stabilising* (look at pKa of acetone); or *not very much at all* (look at pKa of toluene), or indeed everything in between.

Comment: @orthocresol I get your point. But why does that make it incomparable with terminal alkynes? Is stabilisation by s character here more prominent than resonance?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna, I'd encourage you to look at it the other way around: instead of trying to use the model to explain the facts, use the facts to refine your model. Our understanding of resonance, inductive effects, etc. and our understanding of how influential they are, are derived only by careful observation of a wide range of chemical properties. So, this is a great example from which you can deduce that *yes*, in this particular case, the hybridisation argument *is* actually far more important than resonance.

Comment: @orthocresol Thanks for your time! I can understand it now!